# Let $\vec {a}=2\vec {i} +\vec {j} -\vec {k}$, $\vec {b}=……$...

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec {a}=2\vec {i}+\vec {j}-\vec {k}$, $\vec {b}=\vec {i}-\vec {j}$ and $\vec {c}=5\vec {i}-\vec {j}+\vec {k}$. Then find a unit vector parallel to $\vec {a}+\vec {b}-\vec {c}$ but in opposite direction.

My Attempt:
$$\vec {a}=(2 ,   1  ,   -1)$$
$$\vec {b}=(1   ,  -1  ,   0)$$
$$\vec {c}=(5  ,  -1  ,   1)$$
Now,
$$=\vec {a}+\vec {b}+\vec {c}$$
$$=(2   ,  1   ,  -1)  +  (1   , -1,    0) + (5 ,   -1,    1)$$
$$(8 ,  -1  ,0)$$.

Now, what should I do further?

Comment: i have another vector $$[-2,1,-2]$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, Could you please add.calculations?

Comment: @Ramanujan it appears you made a calculation error when finding $\vec{a}+\vec{b}-\vec{c}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computed $\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}$ instead of $\vec{a}+\vec{b}-\vec{c}$. Let's call the result of the latter calculation $\vec{V}$. Then $\frac{\vec{V}}{\vec{V}\cdot\vec{V}}$ is a unit vector in the same direction as $\vec{V}$. As we've been asked for the opposite direction, we need $-\frac{\vec{V}}{\vec{V}\cdot\vec{V}}$. Equivalently, you could compute $\frac{\vec{W}}{\vec{W}\cdot\vec{W}}$ with $\vec{W}:=-\vec{V}=\vec{c}-\vec{a}-\vec{b}$.

Answer (score 0):

the searched vector is given by $$\vec{a}+\vec{b}-\vec{c}=(2+1-5;1-1+1;-1-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Then find $\dfrac{-(\vec{a}+\vec{b}-\vec{c})}{||\vec{a}+\vec{b}-\vec{c}||}$ that's the unit vector